# I try to create code that display its given arguments in reverse order, but why does it code tell me segmentation fault?

Tags: c

As you can see the tile, I try to create code that display its given arguments in reverse order. but it keeps giving me segmentations fault. I tried and tried to figure it out, but don't understand why. Please giving me kind advice and explanation. Thank you all

```
#include <unistd.h>

void ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

int     main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int j;

    i = argc;
    while(i > 0)
    {
        j = 0;
        while(argv[i][j] != '\0')
        {
            ft_putchar(argv[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i--;
        ft_putchar('\n');
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: [This `main` function reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) might be helpful. Carefully note what `argv[argc]` is.

Comment: `for (j = argc-1; j >= 0; j--) printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", j, argv[j]);`

Comment: In C, the valid index into an array (`argv[]` is an array ) has the range 0...(number of elements in array -1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the below line of code:

```
while(argv[i][j] != '\0')
```

when `i == argc`, you will access a null pointer and indexing further on this is undefined behavior which in this case leads to segmentation fault.

> Pointer to an array of pointers to null-terminated multibyte strings that represent the arguments passed to the program from the execution environment (`argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]`). The value of `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be ​0​.

Comment: You're close, but not really correct. `argv[argc]` is actually a valid entry and not out of bounds. It is however specified to always be a null pointer.

Comment: ah! it works now!
so I need to change:
i = argc; --> i = argv - 1;

P.S. It works now, but still confuse. 
will look up carefully your link @Someprogrammerdude. Thank you all!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thanks, updated. Please see if this is okay.